# Detect what site is loading my images

Tags: facebook, express

I'm attempting to make a shareable gif on facebook that will link back to my main site when it's clicked on.

To do this, I need to know if facebook is loading the image, or if the image is being viewed directly. Here are the two scenarios and actions that need to happen in each

1. gif is being loaded by facebook

   - send the gif
2. gif is being viewed directly

   - redirect to site root

Is there some field in the request object that I can use to determine this?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the HTTP origin header, but it is often supressed for security and privacy reasons.

Comment: it should be set always by FB scraper, though, right?